# Find the ngDocs comments that have no methodOf (regex)

Tags: angularjs, regex, format, phpstorm

I have built an angular1 application, which has thousands of methods in many many controllers, etc.
During the development, I wasn't too careful when creating docs comments. I have spent the night fixing the format to be able to generate docs, again.

Now I get this error message: `Don't know how to format @ngdoc: method`.
I have learned from other, similar questions, that this happens (or might happen), when the `@methodOf` attribute is missing. The Error message does not clarify *where* this happens.

So I'd like to find all those ngdoc comments, which are not properly formatted, using the IDEs (PhPStorm) search function and a regular expression.

This the current Expression, that I have come up with:

`\/\*\*\s*\n\s\*\s@ngdoc method\n(\s\*.*(?<!methodOf)\n)*\s\*\/`

From these comments, I'd like it to find the second one, only:

```
/** 
 * @ngdoc method
 * @name app.admin:AuditLogController#auditsWatch
 * @methodOf app.admin:AuditLogController
 */


/**
 * @ngdoc method
 * @name app.admin:AuditLogController#auditsWatch
 */


/**
 * @name app.admin:AuditLogController#auditsWatch
 */
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/wfIiZJ/1

So basically I'd like it to find any comment, that starts off with 
`/**` and `@ngdoc method`, ends with `*/`and does not have `methodOf` somewhere in between.

The closest I have come, is this one:
`\/\*\*\s\n*.*(?!methodOf)\n*.*\n\s\*\/`
https://regex101.com/r/qpt8G7/1

I'll continue trying, but maybe someone has the solution and is willing to share.
Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `(?s)\/\*\*\s*\*\s*@ngdoc method\n(?:(?!\*\/|methodOf).)*\s\*\/`

Comment: Thanks, I just got it myself. If you like, you can post this as an answer, though. This works, too, so I would gladly marks it as correct.

Comment: Good, I added mine with some explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) here:

```
(?s)\/\*\*\s*\*\s*@ngdoc method\n(?:(?!\*\/|methodOf).)*\s\*\/
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iCATWM/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(?s)` - enables `.` to match line breaks
- `\/\*\*` - a literal `/**` substring
- `\s*\*\s*` - a `*` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `@ngdoc method\n` - literal `@ngdoc method` substring followed with a newline
- `(?:(?!\*\/|methodOf).)*` - the tempered greedy token matching any char, 0 or more times, that is not the starting point of a `*/` literal char sequence or `methodOf` substring
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\*\/` - a `*/` literal char sequence.

Note that you may consider using `\R` or `\r?\n` to match line breaks if there may be a CR before LF.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so right after I posted the question and thought it through from the beginning, I got the solution.

The regex looks like this:
`(\/\*\*\s*\n\s*\*\s@ngdoc method\n)(((\s\*\s)(?!@methodOf).*\s*\n)*)\s*\*\/`
https://regex101.com/r/Ep50XQ/1/

I divided it into several groups.

`(\/\*\*\s*\n\s*\*\s@ngdoc method\n)` finds

```
/**
 * @ngdoc method
```

So any comment which documents a method.

```
(\s\*\s)
```

Takes care of a new comment line, consisting of possible white spaces, one *, followed by more whitespaces.

Here lies the culprit I fell into before.
I need to be aware of the current cursors position.

```
(?!@methodOf)
```

Makes sure the line does *not* start with `@methodOf`
In combination `(((\s\*\s)(?!@methodOf).*\s*\n)*)`
ensures a line within the comment, which does not start with `@methodOf`, can have any characters besides (`.*`), possibly some white spaces (`\s`) and ends with a line break. This can be repeated any number of times (`*`).

The last part

```
\s*\*\/
```

is this: `*/`which ends the comment block and the regex.

Thank you, StackOverflow, for helping me think.
Maybe it can help somebody else, though.